How to specify baseUrl for next-auth?
I am trying to implement authentication for my Next JS app with next-auth library. I created my pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts file
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { NEXT_GATEWAY_URL } from "../../../config/requests";
import axios from 'axios';

export default NextAuth({
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },

  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: {},
        password: {},
      },
      async authorize(_credentials, req) {
        ...
      },
    }),
  ],
});

And then I am making request:
const response: any = await signIn("credentials", {
            username: 'admin',
            password: 'admin',
            redirect: false,
});

Inside console, i see multiple 404 errors, like LOG [HTTP] GET /api/auth/providers 404. It looks like it uses wrong baseUrl. My next js app is located on 'localhost:3000/admin/*'. How can I specify/modify my baseUrl to be 'http://localhost:3000/admin'? I tried adding .env variable:
NEXTAUTH_URL="http://localhost:3000/admin, but it did not help
Added NEXTAUTH_URL="http://localhost:3000/admin and restarted application. It did not change anything.

Ok, I just needed to add this NEXTAUTH_URL to next.config file:
module.exports = (_phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
...
env: {
      NEXTAUTH_URL: "http://localhost:3000/admin/api/auth",
    },
}

